# excel multiple column vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

My table

```
Id  index Col1  col2  col3
a    1    smith
a    2           John
b    1    mark
b    2           kay
b    3                 Van
c    1    Par
c    2           Cap
```

In the Vlookup Table

```
ID  Col1   Col2  Col3
a   Smith  John
b   Mark   kay   Van
c   Par    Cap
```

How do I achieve by doing vlookup by id

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you trying to condense your table to the second table?

Comment: Which is the input and which is the output?

Comment: first table input , second table desired output

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will solve your issue:[image: Screenshot(1)]

This is the formula in cell I2:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,0))
```

This is the formula in cell J2:

`=IF(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,0))=0,OFFSET(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,0)),1,0))`

This is the formula in cell K2:

`=IF(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,0))=0,OFFSET(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,0)),2,0))`

Hope this helps!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vlookup instead of index and match, you could use a helper column:

[image]

The formula in cell 1 is:

`=B2&C2`

The formula in cell H2 is:

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($H2&RIGHT(I$1,1),$A$2:$C$8,RIGHT(I$1,1),0)),0,VLOOKUP($H2&RIGHT(I$1,1),$A$1:$F$8,RIGHT(I$1,1)+3,0))`

To make the formula be the same in all cells in the output table, I have used the rightmost character in the column name as an index.  Hard coding this value, or adding a helper row, would make it easier to read.